# Using the perl-based rename command to change filenames commencing with dashes

Tags: perl, command-line, file-rename

`rename` is a perl-based command-line tool to rename multiple files.

I have, by accident, created numerous files with names that commence with, or contain, a dash or double dash (`-` or `--`). When I try to use rename to get rid of the dashes in, for example, '--the-file-name' using

```
rename 's/-//g' --the-file-name
```

rename (understandably) complains that 'the-file-name' is not an allowable option for the rename command.

Is there a way to tell rename that '--the-file-name' is a file name and not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many commands, including Perl's `rename` script, support a double-dash to denote the end of a command's options. Hence, to rename `--the-file-name` to `the-file-name`:

```
rename 's/-//g' -- --the-file-name
```

Perl's [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) module supports this and is used by `rename`.

In general, see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Answer (score 1):

JRFerguson's answer actually works for many commands, not just `rename`.

Some alternatives also work for commands that do not recognize `--`:

- Prefix the filename with `./` or the full path to it:

  ```
  rename 's/-//g' ./--*
  ```

  or

  ```
  rename 's/-//g' $PWD/--*
  ```
- Use `find` (which will also traverse any subdirectories):

  ```
  find . -name '-*' -exec rename 's/-//g' '{}' ';'
  ```

  or

  ```
  find . -name '-*' -exec rename 's/-//g' '{}' +
  ```

Comment: Note that `rename` applies the transformation to the pathname(s) exactly as given, not just the last component, so `rename 's/-//g' $PWD/--*` will be bad if `$PWD` has any dashes in it.

Comment: Good point. The `find` solution will also pass (relative) pathnames to `rename`.